# Rsync include from and exclude from a list

Tags: rsync, syntax

I am trying to use rsync include-from and exclude-from commands to ignore or only copy listed files/directories from a source. The list is in a text file. For some reason the command does not execute. Why is this the case?

Code:

```
rsync -ar —exclude-from 'exclude-list.txt' source/* destination/

rsync -ar —include-from 'exclude-list.txt' source2/* destination/
```

In exclude-list.txt:

```
file1
file2
/dir1
/dir2
```

Comment: cross-posting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49382297/2351568

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
rsync -a —exclude-from='exclude-list.txt' source/ destination/
```

Note the `=` between the option and the filename.

Also, the `--archive` (`-a`) option implies `-r`, so `-r` is not needed.

I've also removed `*` from `source/*`.  The above command will copy all files and directories in or below `source` to `destination` (including hidden names), except the things matching the patterns in the exclude file.